# Ant junitlauncher task does not run tests

Tags: ant, junit5

I have an ant target to run junit5 tests via `junitlauncher` :

```xml
    <target name="juint" depends="build">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <junitlauncher haltOnFailure="true" printSummary="true">
            <!-- include the app code & libraries required to run the tests -->
            <classpath>
                <path refid="datastudio-trunk-java-lib.classpath" />
                <pathelement location="target/classes"/>
            </classpath>

            <classpath>
                <!-- the test classes themselves -->
                <pathelement location="target/test-classes"/>
            </classpath>
            <testclasses outputdir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <fileset dir="target/test-classes">
                    <include name="**/*.class"/>
                </fileset>
                <listener type="legacy-brief" sendSysOut="true"/>
                <listener type="legacy-xml" sendSysErr="true" sendSysOut="true"/>
            </testclasses>
        </junitlauncher>
    </target>
```

The task finds my tests, but does not run them, as we can see in the output :

```
[junitlauncher] Test run finished after 31 ms
[junitlauncher] [         2 containers found      ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 containers skipped    ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 containers started    ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 containers aborted    ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 containers successful ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 containers failed     ]
[junitlauncher] [         5 tests found           ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 tests skipped         ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 tests started         ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 tests aborted         ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 tests successful      ]
[junitlauncher] [         0 tests failed          ]
```

I have a simple junit test class which defines 5 tests like this :

```java
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
class JDBC {

    private static Logger log = null;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setLogger() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "../log4j2.xml");
        log = LogManager.getLogger("fr.data.datastudio.test");
        log.info("logging enabled");
    }

    // [...]

    @Test
    void testSqlite() {
        Jdbc4Jni db = connect("org.sqlite.JDBC", "jdbc:sqlite::memory:", null, null);
        _testTypes(db);
    }
}
```

The tests runs OK in eclipse Junit view, but not from ant. Do anyone know why they are found but not started (nor skipped) ?

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I've just got some junit 5 tests working with ant (1.10.7) and I don't use any `@RunWith` tags. Just `@Test` and it works.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@RunWith` tag?

Comment: Same result: 6 tests found, 0 tests started